# What's this file in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, file-type

[image]

It is not really existing in the folder of the project but somewhere else, is it a refrence file?

Comment: Can you show us the extensions of the files as well?

Comment: @bonCodigo The extensions can be all file, so it doesn't matter what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That icon displayed means its a file referenced from a folder outside the Solution. Visual Studio C# Solutions generally show the file system directory that project file is in. Files outside of that are shown as being linked in, or referenced, by that icon you see there. See [`Adding as a Link`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: @ThePhD, do extentions look *all file* as per Wayou? or does it have either `.cs` for those marked with `c#`, `resx` or `xsd`? So how can OP say *it doesn't matter*?

Comment: hi @bonCodigo, I'm not so sure if all files can be added as a link to the project, maybe not all, I made a mistake to say"it doesn't matter waht the extension is."

Comment: You can add any file you want to a Visual Studio solution, so long as it's reasonably findable on the File System.